# Mocking not working as expected

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I have a method that calls the [set_status api of the webapp2.Response class](https://github.com/moraes/webapp-improved/blob/master/webapp2.py#L380):

```
class RequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  some_method(self):
    self.response.set_status(200)
```

I am writing tests for `some_method()` and mocking the `set_status` method:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    # Set up stuff.

  @mock.patch.object(Response, 'set_status')
  def testSomeMethod()
    some_method()
```

However when I run the test I get:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_status'

Why is the call to `set_status()` not getting mocked?

Comment: Please write your test code. Like it is there are no chances to write an answer. The issue is in `patch` call but without knowing the context we should guess too much. Just one shot: try to use `mock.patch("webapp2.Response.set_satus")` instead.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico Added the test code. Please take a look. Using mock.patch("webapp2.Response.set_satus") didn't help.

Comment: Please and also how you import `Response` in test module. It will be useful to have the exact stack trace error. Just a question: did you have the same error by use `mock.patch("webapp2.Response.set_satus")`?

Comment: @Micheled'Amico `from webapp2 import Response`. I got the same error when using `mock.patch("webapp2.Response.set_satus")`. Sorry I won't be able to share the stack trace, it may reveal some confidential company code.

Comment: Ok, I'm quite sure that the `patch` doesn't mater in this context: maybe `self.response` is `None` in `some_method()`

Comment: @Michele d'Amico Yep, that was the problem. It's now resolved. Thank you !!